# Kubernetes - Nginx Frontend & Django Backend

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm following along this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/ the mainly difference is that my app is a Djago app running on port 8000.

The frontend pod keeps crashing:

> ```
> 2021/03/15 00:15:52 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "posi:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/posi.conf:2
> nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "posi:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/posi.conf:2
> ```

Could someone point out my mistakes, please.

**deploy_backend.yaml**

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: posi-backend
> spec:
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: posi
>       tier: backend
>       track: stable
>   replicas: 2
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: posi
>         tier: backend
>         track: stable
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: posi-backend
>         image: xxxxxxxxxx.yyy.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/posi/posi:uwsgi
>         command: ["uwsgi"]
>         args: ["--ini", "config/uwsgi.ini"]
>         ports:
>         - name: http
>           containerPort: 8000
>       imagePullSecrets:
>         - name: regcred
> ```

**service_backend.yaml**

> ```
>  apiVersion: v1
>  kind: Service
>  metadata:
>    name: posi-backend
>  spec:
>    selector:
>      app: posi
>      tier: backend
>    ports:
>    - protocol: TCP
>      port: 8000
>      targetPort: 8000
> ```

**deploy_frontend.yaml**

> ```
>  apiVersion: apps/v1
>  kind: Deployment
>  metadata:
>    name: posi-frontend
>  spec:
>    selector:
>      matchLabels:
>        app: posi
>        tier: frontend
>        track: stable
>    replicas: 1
>    template:
>      metadata:
>        labels:
>          app: posi
>          tier: frontend
>          track: stable
>      spec:
>        containers:
>          - name: posi-frontend
>            image: alx/urn_front:1.0
>            lifecycle:
>              preStop:
>                exec:
>                  command: ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-s", "quit"]
> ```

**service_frontend.yaml**

> ```
>  apiVersion: v1
>  kind: Service
>  metadata: 
>    name: posi-frontend
>  spec: 
>    selector:
>      app: posi
>      tier: frontend
>    ports:
>    - protocol: "TCP"
>      port: 80
>      targetPort: 80
>    type: NodePort
> ```

**nginx.conf**

> ```
> upstream posi_backend {
>     server posi:8000;
> }
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name qa-posi;
>      location /static/ {
>          alias /code/static/;
>      }
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://posi_backend;
>         include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
>     }
> }
> ```

- #### Cluster information:
- Kubernetes version: 1.20
- Cloud being used: bare-metal
- Installation method: Kubeadm
- Host OS: Centos 7.9
- CNI and version: Weave 0.3.0
- CRI and version: Docker 19.03.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You named your Service (and your Pod) `posi-backend`, but your nginx configuration tries to connect to:

```
upstream posi_backend {
    server posi:8000;
}
```

It should rather connect to `posi-backend`.

```
upstream posi_backend {
    server posi-backend:8000;
}
```

Comment: As I read the docs I understood that what was supposed to be in server in upstream was what was in matchLabels: app: posi. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexandreCardoso https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/